# How to deal with imputation of large continuous intervals of missing data in time series?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, data-imputation, signal-processing

Imagine you have a dataframe of historical sensory data measurements, such as temperature and energy consumption, recorded **every 15 minutes for 2 years**.

**What would be the most appropriate way to deal with entire chunks of missing data?**

Imagine **an entire week or two are missing**, there are no points in between, and we want to avoid dropping records or using unrealistically simple methods like linear regression or backfilling, the **imputation should try and recreate the missing records** based on **the rest of the known time series history**.

What methods could I use?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's 1% or 50% of the series' information that you're imputing: a sound imputation procedure accurately reflects the fraction of lost information in the form of increased variability. In total however, some information may be recovered depending how auto correlated the series is.

Comment: I'm not talking about percentage of missing points, I'm talking about entirely missing chunks of data, where the model should be able to recostrunct seasonal and cyclical patterns instead of just interpolating very close timestamps.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Amelia (and now there's Amelia II), but you might check it out.  https://gking.harvard.edu/amelia   What I liked about it is that it provided multiple alternative imputations, so you had an (admittedly imperfect) way to see if your conclusions depended on a particular imputation result.

Comment: @9879ypxkj well it depends on your ability to specify the correct imputation model. Building something custom is preferable to off the shelf imputers because you can explicitly write imputation model. But like I said we don't care about "chunks" versus "percents" of missing data. More imputation = more assumptions.

Comment: @AdamO That doesn't make much sense, if you're missing 50% of the points, one thing is if they're alternating points (in that case you can reconstruct much of the information just by connecting the dots) and one thing is if you're missing the whole first half of the time series. The assumptions and models needed should be different.